# Why is the background color not changing if I click the change button?

Tags: html

I'm a beginner in html and i want to create a site where you have 4 buttons: 1 for changing the Red, 1 for changing the Green, 1 for changing the Blue and 1 for setting the background color to the given color(The Red, Green, Blue or RGB). But I don't know why this is not working. I hope someone can help.

I have tried to change some things but it just would not work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    
     <button onclick="SetR()">Change Red</button>    
    
     <button onclick="SetG()">Change Green</button>     
    
     <button onclick="SetB()">Change Blue</button>     
    
     <button onclick="Change()">Change the color!</button>     
    

    <script type="text/javascript">
     
    function SetR() {
     var a = parseInt(prompt("Enter R"),10);
     }
    
     function SetG() {
    var b = parseInt(prompt("Enter G"),10);
    }
    
     function SetB() {
      var c = parseInt(prompt("Enter B"),10);
     }
    
      function Change() {
     document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(" + [a,b,c].join() + ")";
     }
    
     </script>
    
    </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you provide more details about what's not working, and what your expected result is?

Comment: "I expect someone to fix my code"... ??

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a free code-fixing service or something like that.

Comment: Let's not be hasty, there may be a language/culture barrier here. @narwalmanu that last line comes across as arrogant and demanding. Please consider removing it. If you are in fact being arrogant and demanding, let me know how that works out for you.

Comment: I'm sorry, this is my first question on stackoverflow I removed that line of text. and I added some details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i think you want to change the whole body tag background?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    
     <button onclick="SetR()">Change Red</button>    
    
     <button onclick="SetG()">Change Green</button>     
    
     <button onclick="SetB()">Change Blue</button>     
    
     <button onclick="Change()">Change the color!</button>     
    

    <script type="text/javascript">
     var a;
     var b;
     var c;
    function SetR() {
     a = parseInt(prompt("Enter R"),10);
     }
    
     function SetG() {
    b = parseInt(prompt("Enter G"),10);
    }
    
     function SetB() {
       c = parseInt(prompt("Enter B"),10);
     }
    
      function Change() {
     document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(" + [a,b,c].join() + ")";
     }
    
     </script>
    
    </body>
     </html>
```